# What is the JavaScript Timer resolution for common configs of IE 7,8 and 9 on XP, Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer

I am researching JavaScript timer resolutions for various IE/Windows combinations . On my IE9/Vista box, I'm getting a 17ms timer resolution (from running [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/rgrove/rQtUU/embedded/result/).) I don't have access to these other combinations. (I don't know if this should be a community wiki question, but here goes anyway)

```
           XP       Vista      Win7
           --        --         --
IE7        ?          ?         ?
IE8        ?          ?         ?
IE9        ?          ?         ?
```

Comment: i ran that test on win7-x64 IE9, result: 3ms

Comment: This would seem to be hardware dependent, no?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll want more than one response for each as hardware would have some impact on the results too (I think?) In any case, Win7x64 IE (32 and 64 bit) give me 4ms.

Comment: Also, wouldn't this vary depending on how overloaded the PC was at the time? Additionally, if the browser also has lots of tabs (with other timers running), then I'd suspect that would have an impact too.

Comment: Good modern browsers like chrome 20 are able to handle lots and lots of concurrent timers (100+) while maintaining a 4ms javascript timer resolution. It's less dependent on system load than you'd think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I discovered that prior to Window 7, the IE javascript timer just called the windows system timer which is 64 ticks per second - or 15.6ms intervals. In Windows 7, there are actually two timer settings. A 4ms timer which applies when you are plugged in, and the old 15.6ms timer that applies when you are unplugged. This is a power saving measure that is actually configurable from the advanced power configuration setting interface - so you can switch your personal machine to have 15.6ms or 4ms in all cases, or if you want to be perverse - to have the high power consumption when you're unplugged and low power consumption when you're plugged.

Answer (score 0):

There is no accurate timer resolution on any operating system for standard timing calls (and this includes Javascript - though I do notice that comments, and the test you've linked, are running at about 4 ms on average, which indicates some complexity beyond the answer I've provided).

In general, timer calls for the standard timing functions for any programming language are tied to the underlying resolution of the operating system's low-resolution timer, which is not guaranteed to increment after an exact number of milliseconds, but is *approximately* 15 ms on all common operating systems (including all versions of Linux, as well as Windows and OSX).

What this means is that the operating system will intermittently check to see if the time has arrived for *any* timing requests made by *any* running program (assuming that that the low-resolution timing functions were called), regardless of the programming language in which those scripts/programs were written.  If so, the system schedules the corresponding callback function for the next time slice of the target program in question.

On the average, the low-resolution timer increments about every 15 ms - but this is an average; it varies for any individual increment of the timer, typically up to 25 ms on the high end and ~8 ms on the low end.  That's the nature of the low-resolution system timer - it is very low impact on performance of the system as a whole (and individual programs), but it has an accuracy of only ~15 ms.  In other words, the *precision* is 1 ms (that is why standard timing functions, such as the Javascript timing functions, have ms precision), but the *accuracy* is only ~15 ms, give or take.  The precision and the accuracy are different.

The reason that the low-resolution timer functions this way is for exactly the reason I mentioned - so that timing functions are low-impact on the system.  Higher resolution timing functions exist, but are much more intensive, requiring many CPU cycles just to test and update the timer.  The highest-accuracy timers require additional physical hardware components in conjunction with hardware interrupts, and sometimes necessitate exclusive high-priority access by mission-critical programs.

The bottom line is that Javascript timing functions are not exact.  They will trigger, on average, within about 15 ms of the target time, sometimes less, sometimes more.

Comment: Hi Dan. This used to be correct but is no longer. All recent non-IE browsers run at 4ms on Windows Vista, for example, by using the high resolution timer. For more detail on Chrome's implementation: http://www.belshe.com/2010/06/04/chrome-cranking-up-the-clock/